Unable to create hotspot
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 Noble kernel generation is 6+, I was trying to create a hotspot using hostapd, but my other device can't connect to this hotspot.
here is the config file of hostapd
interface=wlp1s0
driver=nl80211
ssid=MyHotspot
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=12345678
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

And the log suggested that there is something wrong with authetication? On the phone it will just say connection failed
16:07:43 Pantheon hostapd[834133]: wlx30de4be0eca9: STA 12:e2:ce:0a:38:64 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
16:07:45 Pantheon hostapd[834133]: wlx30de4be0eca9: STA 12:e2:ce:0a:38:64 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
16:07:46 Pantheon hostapd[834133]: wlx30de4be0eca9: STA 12:e2:ce:0a:38:64 IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to inactivity (timer DEAUTH/REMOVE)
16:08:35 Pantheon hostapd[834133]: wlx30de4be0eca9: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
16:08:35 Pantheon hostapd[834133]: wlx30de4be0eca9: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
16:08:44 Pantheon hostapd[834133]: wlx30de4be0eca9: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request
16:10:20 Pantheon systemd[1]: Stopping hostapd.service - Access point and authentication server for Wi-Fi and Ethernet...

then I tried on with another network adapter, this time if I press connect on phone, it will stuck is a infinite loop
16:12:18 Pantheon hostapd[841453]: wlp1s0: STA 12:e2:ce:0a:38:64 RADIUS: starting accounting session C65F3D39E97FEC78
16:12:18 Pantheon hostapd[841453]: wlp1s0: STA 12:e2:ce:0a:38:64 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
16:12:22 Pantheon hostapd[841453]: wlp1s0: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
16:12:22 Pantheon hostapd[841453]: wlp1s0: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
16:12:29 Pantheon hostapd[841453]: wlp1s0: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
16:12:29 Pantheon hostapd[841453]: wlp1s0: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
16:12:37 Pantheon hostapd[841453]: wlp1s0: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
16:12:37 Pantheon hostapd[841453]: wlp1s0: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
16:12:44 Pantheon hostapd[841453]: wlp1s0: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
16:12:44 Pantheon hostapd[841453]: wlp1s0: STA f2:56:10:c8:df:f9 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)

